# rxjs Observable merge doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I need to produce this result for a POST request:

```
{
"names": [
    {
        "id": "t3xcb9xAyX",
        "username": "Gennaro"
    },
    {
        "id": "Csdu65RKon",
        "username": "Marco"
    },
    ...
],
"createdAt":"04/07/2018 - 11.49.51"
}
```

so I've done this job, using rxjs: I've created two Observable (one for names, one for createdAt) and merge at the end:

```
const notObj = utils.getNotificationType(codeProduct, Parse);
const csvObj = utils.getNotificationType(codeProduct, Parse);

const query = new Parse.Query(notObj);
const dateQuery = new Parse.Query(csvObj).descending('createdAt');


const names = from(query.find())
    .map(el => el.map((e) => {
        return {
            id: e.id,
            username: e.get('username')
        }
    }))
    .mergeMap((arr) => Observable.of({
        names: arr
    }));

const lastUpdate = from(dateQuery.first())
    .map(res => moment(res.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm:ss'))
    .map(res => {
        return {
            createdAt: res
        }
    });


merge(names, lastUpdate)
    .subscribe(
        (data) => res.send(serialize(data)),
        (error) => res.send(serialize(error)),
        () => console.log('complete')
    );
```

the problem is that finally merge retrieve me only `"names"`. I could have another result using `.zip()` operator, but I have a JSON array instead an object.

My question is: why `merge()` doesn't merge two result but only the first? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not what `merge` does. It merges Observable streams not objects themselves. Use `forkJoin` instead that will emit an array of results and then merge it yourself with `map`:

```
const names$ = ...;
const lastUpdate$ = ...;

forkJoin(names$, lastUpdate$)
  .map(([ names, lastUpdate ]) => ({ names, lastUpdate }))
  .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: what is the difference between forkJoin() and zip() ? I've tried and they are similar

Comment: `forkJoin` stores the last value from each source Observable and emits a single array with last values from all source Observables when all of them complete. `zip` emits every time all source Observables emit `N` values (eg. when you have 2 Observables and the first one emits 4 valeus and the second one only 2 two values then `zip` will emit two arrays with the first and second value from each source Observable).